# BadContextToken in SoapUI

Tags: soapui

I see numerous examples of this error being documented for SoapUI users. The solutions offered to date are to make changes to the server settings. Well in my case the server is not mine.

So, is there any way to know what the underlying setting is on the server, and change the setting in SoapUI to reflect that?

Comment: Please see if this helps - http://nzpcmad.blogspot.in/2012/02/wcf-soapui-error.html

Comment: Unfortunately that is an example of a change on the server side. I do not have access to the server.